# Como criptografar GET e copiar o parametro

Tags: php, mysql, criptografia

Tenho um e-mail de *feedback* que é enviado para um usuário após o serviço ser completado. Esse email tem 5 links, onde cada um é a nota respectiva do serviço (de 1 a 5).

Quero ao direcionar para a página atualizar no banco de dados, a avaliação do serviço, usando o `id` do cliente, do prestador, do pedido e a nota.

Para isso usei link como.. `/avaliacao.php?prestador=1&cliente=2&pedido=3&avaliacao=4`

No PHP, estou usando `$_GET['prestador']` pra pegar os parâmetros e defino a variável que será inserida em um banco de dados MySQL, mas não quero que o cliente veja essa `url`, para ele não alterar da forma que ele quiser.

Como posso fazer? Criptografar? Há outra forma?

Comment: Ja pensou em utilizar `POST`?

Comment: mas daí cada link seria um formulario?
vou usar assim, link1 avaliacao=1, link2 avaliacao=2...etc. Esses links estarão no email enviado

Comment: Não entendi, poderia postar o codigo do seu back end tambem, assim fica mais facil ajudar

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo se vc quiser ofuscar os parâmetros vc pode usar as funções `urlencode()` e `base64_encode()`, depois é só decodificar.

Comment: Mas como o @RafaelAugusto disse, seria melhor utilizar o verbo `POST` para este cenário.

Comment: consegui. fazendo o post igual vc falou, vou postar aqui como ficou, BRIGADÃO!!

Comment: POST não vai garantir segurança, o ideal para evitar a manipulação creio eu, seria um TOKEN unico e exclusivo que já conteria os dados prestador e cliente e pedido e depois de usado, o tal TOKEN não poderia mais ser reutilizado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um simples HMAC para verificar se o `id` permanece inalterado, isso será seguro enquanto ninguém souber a chave utilizada por você, lógico ela deve ser forte e gerada de forma segura, explicarei isto também.

Além disso você deve ter certeza que não se pode obter HMACs de outras contas, caso contrário seria o mesmo que ele ter a chave.

---

> */!\ Não utilize as chaves mencionadas nos exemplos.*

Em geral, ficará algo do tipo:

```
$id = '1234'; 
// Este é o id do usuário, que deve estar associado de alguma forma segura.

$chave = pack('H*', '07e8796b87caa27d793dbe2ecfa7c85f753a9c920cb5d1394fbc36c20f1755b818c9afe37fb453ebf42724c8670d365ca9f0d12d49e31ea843023126f3174df9');
// Esta sua chave secreta e segura que foi gerada por você.

$hmac = hash_hmac('sha512', $id, $chave);
// Este é o resultado do HMAC de SHA-512.


<form action="avaliacao.php" method="post">

<input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?= $id ?>" />
<input name="hmac" type="hidden" value="<?= $hmac ?>" />


<input type="submit" name="avaliacao" value="1" />
<!-- ... Resto das outras opções  -->
</form>
```

Depois para verificar se houve alteração:

```
$chave = pack('H*', '07e8796b87caa27d793dbe2ecfa7c85f753a9c920cb5d1394fbc36c20f1755b818c9afe37fb453ebf42724c8670d365ca9f0d12d49e31ea843023126f3174df9');

if(!isset($_POST['hmac'], $_POST['id'])) {
    echo 'Erro: faltam dados';
    exit;
}

$isHMACValido = hash_equals(
    hash_hmac('sha512', $_POST['id'], $chave),
    $_POST['hmac']
);
// Comparamos de maneira segura e em tempo contante o HMAC enviado pelo usuário e o computado agora.

if(!$isHMACValido){
    echo 'Erro: Dados foram manipulados';
    exit;
}

// Chegou até aqui está tudo certo!
// ...
```

---

**Qual proteção que isso trás?**

- Contra alteração do `id` por um usuário que desconhece a chave.

**Como essa proteção é alcançada?**

- O HMAC é uma opção do tipo `H(K⊕opad||H((K⊕ipad)||m)`, portanto duas mensagens (`m`, neste caso o `id`) diferentes resultam em um HMAC diferente. Um usuário malicioso poderá modificar ambos (exemplo, enviar: `id=99&hmac=aaaa`), mas isto será comparado com o novo HMAC (nós faremos o hmac(id, chave)), óbvio que será diferente da hash enviada pelo usuário.

**Isto não tem risco?**

Do HMAC...

- Ataques de CPA não funcionam, mesmo que o atacante crie milhares de contas (assim tendo vários HMACs válidos para cada conta) ele não terá nenhuma indicio de qual é a chave utilizada.
- Ataques de busca exaustiva sempre vão funcionar, porém são 512 bits, isso resulta em mais de [2^512](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E512) possibilidades, o que inviabiliza o ataque, ao menos até este momento.
- Ataques de busca exaustiva contra a chave também funcionam. Para isso a chave deve ser segura e gerada de um CSPRNG seguro e forte o suficiente, caso contrário ataques de força bruta serão rápidos, utilize também 512 bits de chave.
- Ataques de MiTM são válidos. Se não utilizar HTTPS uma pessoa monitorando a rede poderá obter o HMAC do outro usuário, isto não afetaria somente o HMAC, mas todo o sistema.

Da aplicação...

- Não deve ser possível o usuário ter acesso aos HMACs outros usuários. O `id` deve ser unicamente dele. Sua aplicação não deve dizer qual é o HMAC de um X, sendo X enviado pelo usuário, permitir isto anulará toda segurança.
- A chave deve ser mantida em segredo e não deve ser conhecido pelo cliente, se a chave for exposta será possível computar HMACs válidos.

---

Para gerar uma chave segura utilize:

```
echo unpack('H*', random_bytes(32))[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Conforme o Rafael Augusto Falou, alterei usando o POST, aí ficou assim:

email:

```
<form action="avaliacao.php" method="post">
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="1" />
<input type="submit" name="avaliacao" value="1" />
<input type="submit" name="avaliacao" value="2" />
<input type="submit" name="avaliacao" value="3" />
<input type="submit" name="avaliacao" value="4" />
<input type="submit" name="avaliacao" value="5" />
</form>
```

avaliacao.php

```
<?php

$id = $_POST['id'];
$avaliacao = $_POST['avaliacao'];
echo 'id: '.$id.' - Avaliação: '.$avaliacao.'<br/>';

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db');
$sqlverifica = '
SELECT avaliacao
FROM prestadores_avaliacao
WHERE id = '.$id;
$result = $conn->query($sqlverifica);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $avaliacaoatual = $row["avaliacao"];
    echo "Avaliação Original: ".$avaliacaoatual;
}

if($avaliacaoatual==''){
$sql = '
UPDATE prestadores_avaliacao
SET avaliacao = '.$avaliacao.'
WHERE id = '.$id;
$conn->query($sql);
}

?>
```

Comment: O POST não muda em nada, continua sendo possível alterar os dados.